# UIScrollView doesn't scroll with method scrollRectToVisible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a question for you!

I have a method:

```
- (void)pushNewTableViewController:(NewTableViewController *)newTableViewController
{
    [self addChildViewController:newTableViewController];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:newTableViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectZero;

        frame.origin.x = COLUMN_WIDTH * self.navigationStack.count;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
        frame.size.width = COLUMN_WIDTH;
        frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;

        newTableViewController.view.frame = frame;
    }

    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [self.navigationStack addObject:newTableViewController];

        self.scrollView.contentSize = [self sizeForContent];

        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:newTableViewController.view.frame animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Basically, this method works fine, except the line `[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:newTableViewController.view.frame animated:YES];`.

The idea of this method is to scroll the scroll view to the right to make `newTableViewController.view.frame` to be fully visible. But instead of this, scroll view doesn't scroll anywhere...

Maybe any one of you, guys, know why it doesn't work as I expect?

Comment: Did you debug the `newTableViewController.view.frame` ? What is the CGRect of it?

Comment: Yes I did. It has a correct frame. Also, scroll view frame at the line `[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:newTableViewController.view.frame animated:YES];` is correct too.

Comment: `newTableViewController.view.frame` equals to `(960 0; 320 768)` and `self.scrollView.frame` equals to `(0 0; 1024 768)`.

Comment: So here is your issue.... use the `newTableViewController.view.bounds` instead of the frame and it should work

Comment: It doesn't work too... Where is the issue?

Comment: Use this `[self. scrollView setContentOffset:newTableViewController.view.frame.origin animated:YES];`

Comment: You see, the problem is that by choosing your option I can align `newTableViewController` to left side of main screen, but I need to make it for right.

Comment: Please ensure your scrollview's content size is greater than scrollview's frame.

Comment: Content size: `(width=2240, height=704)`. Scroll view frame: `frame = (0 64; 1024 704)`.